# Flipping bits in an integer without bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, hlsl

I need to flip the bits in an integer from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1.  E.g `10010` to `01101`. The problem is that in HLSL ps_3_0 there are no binary operators.  No ~, <<, >>,...

Is there a mathematical way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: He mentioned that bitwise operators are no available in HLSL so it won't be a great use for him.

Comment: @Elvithari sorry I misread the question

Comment: Not familiar with HLSL, thus only a comment: Shouldn't this be possible by simply subtracting the value from a value with all bits set? E.g. 11111 - 10010 = 01101 (some possible caveats with sign bits etc, but at least in general, I think this could work...)

Comment: This really depends on the desired outcome. If the author wants to literally flip the whole integer, then what you, and @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc suggest would be the solution. If however, he'd like to flip it only up to the most significant bit of his number, he needs another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution

```c
int inverse(int x)
{
    return 0xFFFFFFFFU - x;
}
```

otherwise:

```c
int inverse(int x)
{
    return -x - 1; // because -x = ~x + 1, only works in 2's complement
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lưu Vĩnh Phúc.  That's exactly what I needed.  I'm a little ashamed that I didn't figure it out immediately but I'm thankful you did.