# How to toggle 1 bit and set 1 bit to 0 in assembly with only XOR,OR,AND?

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators

Currently I'm using a chip from school which has a limited number of instructions. What I want to achieve is first toggling a single bit with mask and then set some bits to zero. Only 3 instructions available: AND, OR, XOR. (no SHIFT NOT instruction)

for example

```
0001 1001   // toggle bit 5
0000 1001   
0001 1001   // set bit 1 to 0
0001 1000
```

I'm trying to generate PWM with H-bridge.

## Edit:

Fixed:

```
; toggle bits
LOAD    R0 [GB+OUTPUT_BUF]
XOR     R0 CONV_FORW_MASK
XOR     R0 FLIP_FORW_MASK
XOR     R0 PUSH_FORW_MASK
XOR     R0 PUSH_BACK_MASK

; set mask bit to zero  
LOAD    R1 PUSH_FORW_MASK
XOR     R1 -1
AND     R0 [R1]
```

Comment: goto wikipedia and look up the truth table for xor, and and or, the truth table will explain everything.

Comment: without NOT, I can't find a way to do this

Comment: you have everything you need to toggle, set, and clear

Comment: use `xor` to toggle, `and` to clear, `or` to set bit. No usage of `not` here

Comment: `not` is just a `xor` with -1 anyway

Comment: `not` is also a subtraction from -1 or 0xFFFF... like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107095/flipping-bits-in-an-integer?noredirect=1#comment37189022_24107095

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C it will be :

```
unsigned char byte = 0x19;

unsigned char bit_set = (0x01 & byte) ^ byte;

unsigned char bit_toggle = ((byte ^ 0x10) & 0x10);

byte = ( byte & 0xEF ) | bit_toggle ;
```

Now translate to assembly.

Comment: to set bit, use `byte | 0x01` instead, simpler and faster. to clear it, use `byte & 0xfe`. to toggle, use `byte ^ 0x01`

Comment: for the toggling, the final `&` is completely redundant

Answer (score 1):

actually, one instruction, NAND (which is AND with result inverted) would be sufficient, as you can build an XOR (hint, hint) from 4 of those.
I'd suggest to start exercising by trying to build an XOR from NANDs only. Then the rest may just fall into place by itself.

Comment: with only a NAND or a NOR instruction you can do any logic functions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic